# Residues and how to calculate them

Tags: complex-analysis

I read an example on how to calculate $\int_{\partial D(0,3)} (1+z+z^2)(e^{1/z}+e^{1/(z-1)}+e^{1/(z-2)})dz$. I know that $$\partial D(0,3)$$ means we are on the circle with radius 3 centered at origin.

Our professor then says:
$\int_{\partial D=(0,3)}f(z)dz=2\pi i\Big[Res((1+z+z^2)e^{1/z},0)+Res((1+z+z^2)e^{1/(z-1)},1)+Res((1+z+z^2)e^{1/(z-2)},2)\Big]$

So far, all good. Next step is:

$(1+z+z^2)e^{1/z}=(1+z+z^2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!z^n}\rightarrow Res=5/3$.

This is the part I get lost on. How on earth does he get 5/3 as an answer? What is the actual calculation behind this? I can't see any of the 4 properties being used and if I try to use them I fail to get any answer what-so-ever.

Thanks in advance, 
Niklas.

Comment: Multiply the first terms of $(1+z+z^2)(1 + \frac 1z + \frac{1}{2z^2} + \ldots)$ and figure out which terms contribute to $1/z$.

Comment: Same question with radius 3: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247543/compute-the-following-integral-where-c-is-the-circle-z-3

Comment: It is really $\partial D(0, 2)$? Because $e^{1/(z-2)}$ has an essential singularity on that circle.

Comment: No,you are correct. I actually meant |z|=3 so thanks! Also, thank you for explaining! :)

Comment: @NiklasStenhall I suggest that you edit your question.

Comment: I did not understand you could edit because of the weird place. I edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because\begin{align}(1+z+z^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!z^n}&=(1+z+z^2)\left(1+\frac1z+\frac1{2z^2}+\frac1{6z^3}+\cdots\right)\\&=z^2+\left(1+1\right)z+\left(\frac12+1+1\right)+\overbrace{\left(\frac16+\frac12+1\right)}^{\phantom{5/3}=5/3}\frac1z+\cdots\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much. I must've messed up doing something because i did not get that answer. I will have to recheck again and see if it works out. Thanks yet again!

Comment: Typo in the first line: $\frac{1}{6z^3}$.

Comment: @NickD I've edited my answer. Thank you.